# QT - why specify parent with graphic widgets?

Tags: qt, widget, parent

Question:
Specifying a parent with Qt is always seem to be a good idea. However I don't understand why it is required in some particular cases. There is plenty examples of using QGraphicsView in the following way:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
    QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView(this);
    ...
}
```

So why this is better than `QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView(NULL)?` in this specific case?

Thank you,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to thank UmNyobe and Anthony for helping me to figure it out.

Anyway, I had to look on QT sources to figure out what's happening behind the curtain.

So I understand the whole QObjects idea as following. When a new QObject is created with a specified parent, the  hidden `QObjectPrivate::setParent_helper(QObject *parent)` function is called. It indeed registers the child with the parent:

```
parent->d_func()->children.append(q); // Strange, they didn't use `this` to register the object :)
```

So technically speaking, creating a child with a parent allows the parent to register the child. Therefore, specifying a parent when creating a child is a useful habit.

In some cases, the parent-child relation is specified later anyway (see Anthony's answer), therefore the parent may not be specified.

Comment: If you have an urge to vote the question or the answer down, don't forget to leave a comment explaining what you think is wrong with the question or the answer.

Answer (score 4):

A QWidget with no parent is actually a top-level window. However, sometimes people omit specifying the parent when creating the QWidget because the parent will automatically be set later, for example when the QWidget is part of a layout. For example:

```
QGraphicsView *vew = new QGraphicsView; // the view has no parent

QBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
layout->addWidget(view);

centralWidget()->setLayout(layout); // this automatically reparents the view to 'this'
```

It doesn't really matter whether you pass `this` to the new QGraphicsView, or reparent it later. I don't think either is better, but I always do the latter because it looks nicer to me.

Comment: Thanks. This what I suspected - the parent view gets the awareness about child views when childs are "inserted" into into it, but not when child views are created. Therefore, there is no need to specify parent while creating a "child". I'd still give UmNyobe a chance to elaborate on his answer. See my comment on his answer.

Answer (score 2):

> "Specifying a parent with Qt is always seem to be a good idea"

There is an [explanation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/objecttrees.html).

In this case it is better to specify a parent because you don't need to manage objects destruction. Think about an application with mutliple windows. With `NULL` everywhere as parent, all objects and their resources are still alive when you close windows. So you create memory leaks. On the other hand, if you have a good object hierarchy, then closing the window will call all the destructors in the hierarchy. One less bug to care about...

> can you please explain how the parent window becomes aware of the child view?

There is an internal functionality for the child to add itself to the parent object. This is definitely used in both the `QObject` constructor and `QObjet::setParent(QObject * parent)` method. You can notice from the signature that there is no `const` anywhere, that's because the child object will modify the parent.

http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qobject.html#details

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain how the parent window becomes aware of the child view when the child is created with a pointer to the parent?Is there a hidden "call back" from the child (through the pointer to the parent) that somehow registers the child view into the parent?